# In Emacs, how to go back to previous line position after using semantic Jump to Symbol?

Tags: emacs

I know how to go to a variable definition in Emacs using `semantic-mode`. It works well in a single file (I think it doesn't work if the definition is in another file). Using `C-c , j`, I can go to the definition of the variable, but, how do I jump back to the previous line? Currently I use display Symref `C-c , g`, and select the displayed symref.

Is there any straight method?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Use:

<kbd>C-u C-space</kbd> or <kbd>C-u C-@</kbd>

If you want to navigate back between buffers, you can use:

<kbd>C-x C-space</kbd> or <kbd>C-x C-@</kbd>

This makes Emacs jump to the mark (and set the mark from position popped off the local mark ring) which has usually been set by a previous jump command.

Comment: nice Thomas! That's working as expected :). Hm, being not able to go to another buffer, is not quite a problem. because Semantic-Mode can not also open definition to another file/buffer. Or, can it?

Comment: I don't know about semantic-mode, but in any case `C-u C-@` would not take you back to the original buffer.

Comment: @Thomas It's been a couple of months since you asked this so it might be a new feature, but yes, semantic can find definitions in other buffers/files and jump to them. When that happens just go back to previous buffer `C-x b RET`, and the point should still be where you left it.

Comment: By the way, `C-x C-space` (instead of C-u) jumps to the global mark, which works even across buffers.

Comment: `C-space` is bound to `set-mark-command`. When invoked with prefix argument, i.e., `C-u C-space`, this function will "jump to the mark, and set the mark from position popped off the local mark ring (this does not affect the global mark ring).  Use [`C-x C-space`] to jump to a mark popped off the global mark ring (see `pop-global-mark`)." This and more information can be found in the documentation for `set-mark-command` which you get to by typing `C-h k C-space`.

Comment: @nephewtom As always, the way you find out which command/function is executed by a key chord is to issue: C-h k. So for example: C-h k C-h k will tell you that C-h k is bound to 'describe-key', which is exactly what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I do not remember when I asked that. Of course I know C-h k, I use it quite often. But since C-u runs _universal-argument_, that might be the reason for my question.

Comment: By the way, I already mentioned `C-h k` in my comment from last September.

Comment: How can I press `C-x C-@` should it be `ctrl+shift+2` ?

Comment: You first press `CTRL` and `x`, and then you press `CTRL` and `@`. You don't have to release `CTRL` for that. Where exactly the `@` sign is on your keyboard depends on your locale / keyboard layout, but note that you can also type `C-x C-space`.