# Eclipse style alt left/right navigation within emacs

Tags: emacs, navigation, elisp, code-navigation

I am switching to emacs and in the process of configuring my emacs environment, I am stuck with implementing a functionality which I used to have in eclipse and IntelliJ. Move back and forth in code with alt left/right keys.

I want it to be able to work across all major modes and across all buffers(not just for java or any specific language). For example,
say I'm at beginning of file1.txt(say `p1`). I search for some text and go to line 10(`p2`) in `file1.txt`. Then I open another file, `file2.txt` and repeat the same , start at line 1(`p3`) and then go to line 10(`p4`). Upon `Alt + Left` and `Alt + right` (or any other similar keybinding), I should be able to cycle between positions `p1 <-> p2 <-> p3 <-> p4`

I am aware of the following.

1. ctags/etags specific approach of generating tags, jumping to functions and then back. But I want it to be applicable to text files and a lot of files for which ctags cant be generated or not worth generating as I use them rarely e.g Makefiles generated from cmake builds etc.
2. Questions, answers and comments in
   https://superuser.com/questions/241939/how-to-jump-back-to-the-last-position-of-the-cursor-in-emacs
   ,
   [In Emacs, how to go back to previous line position after using semantic Jump to Symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918707/in-emacs-how-to-go-back-to-previous-line-position-after-using-semantic-jump-to)
   where answers are mentioned about using mark ring and registers for
   storing mark. But after trying such approach initially, I found that
   once if I go forward, then backward, I pop stuff from the register.
   I need it to be there forever(:D )
3. I read really bad things about icicles and bit hesitant to try
   it.

Any other approach that I have missed ? Any plugin or anything ? Implementing this is a bit complex. I hoping this is a common problem and hoping some piece of elisp code exists for solving this problem.

Comment: Sounds like something useful. If such package doesn't exist yes, it should be relatively easy to implement using a `pre-command-hook` that saves the point position before relevant commands.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is useful .maybe not 
https://github.com/joodland/bm

```
(setq-default
bm-recenter nil
bm-highlight-style 'bm-highlight-line-and-fringe
bm-cycle-all-buffers t
bm-in-lifo-order t)
;; (global-set-key (kbd "M-.") 'bm-toggle); you need set mark before you jump 
;; (global-set-key (kbd "M-/")   'bm-next)
;; (global-set-key (kbd "M-,") 'bm-previous)
```

and I know evil-mode 
C-o evil-jump-backward
C-i evil-jump-forward
whenever you use gg G / it can remember last position

Comment: I do not know whether the answer is correct, but the last four lines should be moved out of the code box, or semicolon delimiters should be added to the left of each line.  Lines 2 to 5 should be slightly indented.